# iOS 7 - Why doesn't ABPersonViewController display all of my person's information?

Tags: ios, ios7, abpersonviewcontroller

I am using ABPersonViewController to display information from the phone's contacts. In iOS6 it works fine and I see all of the fields.

In iOS 7 however, only the name shows up and not the other fields like phone number and address. What do I need to do to make the other fields show up in iOS 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues with this as well.  Once I set the addressBook property on the ABPersonViewController, it starting working as I expected.

addressBook
Optional. The address book from which to obtain the contact to display.
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) ABAddressBookRef addressBook

Comment: Just as a warning to anyone who may have this problem in iOS 8 - I found that if I set the address book before the person then none of the details would display, whereas if I set it after, then everything works as expected!